# Errno2 file not found after working with said path and/or possible bugs i'm overlooking

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I have to create an app that gets a path from the user and renames, after the content of a cell, the entire document (excel documents in this case). For example, if in a specified cells, there is "2", the document will be names 2.xlsx and so on, until al the files are renamed properly.

The problem is that, after verifying that, in the specified path, there are files, python exits with [Errno2] no such file or directory. I've modified the code to add `for files in os.listdir(pathlib.Path(SPEC_PATH).resolve()):`, that apparently solves the issue with the error, but doesn't recognize some components (traceback below).

I tried debugging it, but, to me it seems fine. What might be the problem? Are there some bugs that i need to take care of first?

The code:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
import pathlib
import re
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

# global variables
SPEC_PATH = input("path: ")


def format_date(extracted_string):
    new_s = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", "", extracted_string)
    return new_s


def extract_date(workbook_name):
    for files in os.listdir(pathlib.Path(SPEC_PATH).resolve()):
        if files.endswith(".xlsx") or files.endswith(".xls"):
            new_path = os.path.join(SPEC_PATH, files)
            wb = load_workbook(new_path)
            ws = wb.active
            return ws['C5'].value


# main function
SPEC_PATH = pathlib.Path(SPEC_PATH).resolve()  # will access the given path
count = 0
user_choice = input(
    "Would you like the new name to contain a string before the date?(y/n) ").lower()

while True:
    if user_choice.isalpha():
        if user_choice == 'y':
            head_string = input("Please enter the string: ")
            for x in os.listdir(SPEC_PATH):
                # might include all xl extensions just to be safe
                if x.endswith(".xls") or x.endswith(".xlsx"):
                    extract_date(x)
                    format_date(x)
            for file in os.path.join(SPEC_PATH, file):
                if file.is_file():
                    custom_name = extract_date(file)
                    new_name = f"{head_string}{file.suffix}"
                    if SPEC_PATH.is_file():
                        continue
                    else:
                        try:
                            file.rename(SPEC_PATH/new_name)
                            print("Success!")
                        except OSError as e:
                            print(e)

        else:
            if user_choice == 'n':
                # will count all the files that contain a specified extension
                for files in os.listdir(SPEC_PATH):
                    # might include all xl extensions just to be safe
                    if files.endswith(".xls") or files.endswith(".xlsx"):
                        count += 1
                        extract_date(files)
                        format_date(files)
                        if files.is_file():
                            custom_name = extract_date(files)
                            new_name = f"{files.suffix}"
                            if SPEC_PATH.is_file():
                                continue
                            else:
                                try:
                                    file.rename(SPEC_PATH/new_name)
                                    print("Success!")
                                except OSError as e:
                                    print(e)
    else:
        if user_choice.isnumeric() or user_choice != 'y' or user_choice != 'n':
            print("Please enter a valid choice!")
            break
```

Also, i have this error now:

````
  File "e:\\renameFiles\\smallComponentsTest.py", line 62, in <module>
    if files.is_file():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_file' ```
````

Comment: Please include the complete traceback.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "e:\\smallComponentsTest.py", line 38, in <module>
extract_date(x)
File "e:\\smallComponentsTest.py", line 17, in extract_date
wb = load_workbook(files)
File "C:\Users\\Python310\\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,

Comment: File "C:\Users\\Python310\\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
File "C:\Users\\Python310\\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
File "C:\Users\\Python310\lib\zipfile.py", line 1240, in __init__
self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '100621.xlsx'

Comment: **os.listdir** has no path details i.e. it returns just a directory or filename, like '100621.xlsx'. The default path is where the python file is run so python would be looking for '100621.xlsx' in that path. You would need to include the correct path where the file resides in the **load_workbook** command.

Comment: You should include the traceback in the question.

Comment: i've edited the question to add all the details i could, including the recent bugs, traceback, and updated code

Comment: The python string method is **isfile()** no underline

Comment: Also I think this line would be an issue **for file in os.path.join(SPEC_PATH, file):** there is no indication that 'file' is defined before so how can you use it in the path and define it at the same time,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed all the problems and finished the renaming sequence.

```
import os
import pathlib
```

```
                if user_choice == 'y':
                    head_string = input("Please enter the string: ")

                    # renaming operation
                    for x in os.listdir(SPEC_PATH):
                        full_path = os.path.join(SPEC_PATH, x)
                        extension = pathlib.Path(full_path).suffix
                        custom_name = extract_date(full_path)
                        new_name = f"{head_string}{custom_name}{extension}"
                        try:
                            os.rename(os.path.join(SPEC_PATH, x),
                                      os.path.join(SPEC_PATH, new_name))
                            print("Success!")
                            counter += 1
                        except OSError as e:
                            print(e)
                            counter += 1
```